# number format for .csv using xslt1.0

Tags: xslt

I have tag in xml which value sometimes -ve number and sometimes +ve number and I want to show the -ve(e.g -10) number as (10) I mean with bracket using xslt1.0.

Could you please help me?

I am using below template but it is not working.

```
  <xsl:call-template name="fmtNumber">
           <xsl:with-param name="amt" select="retailer:Amount" />
  </xsl:call-template>
  <xsl:template name="fmtNumber">
        <xsl:param name="amt" />
        <xsl:value-of
        select="format-number($amt, ' $###,##0 ;($###,##0)')" />
  </xsl:template>
```

it is showing the result in csv file as $(10) but, I want (10), I mean without dollar sumbol.

Answer (score 1):

do:

```
<xsl:value-of select="format-number($amt, '###,##0;(###,##0)')"/>
```

Comment: I tried this earlier also but, it is showing -10 it is not showing with bracket

  `<xsl:value-of
   select="format-number($amt, '###,##0;      (###,##0)')" />`

Comment: What XSLT processor are you using? Looks like a non-conformance.

Comment: Please see http://xsltransform.net/gWcDMeu. I tried using Xalan 2.7.1 and Saxon 6.5.5. It works fine.

Comment: @AratKumarrana Which XSLT 1.0 processor specifically?

Comment: @Michael I am using **javax.xml.transform** package for the transformation

Answer (score 1):

Please run the following stylesheet (with any XML source) on your processor and post the resulting code.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:variable name="num" select="-123" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <result>
        <version><xsl:value-of select="system-property('xsl:version')"/></version> 
        <vendor><xsl:value-of select="system-property('xsl:vendor')"/></vendor> 
        <test><xsl:value-of select="format-number($num, '#,##0;(#,##0)')"/></test>
    </result>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I am getting the version as **1** and vendor as **IBM Corporation** because I am using ibmsdk6 and the number as **-123**

Comment: @AratKumarrana That's an incorrect result, and it's not your fault. I suggest using xsl:choose to work around this problem.