# XML split based on sub group -- using XSL

Tags: xslt

I have a case where i need to split XML into multiple based on the sub root section of xml.

For Example - I have;

```
<rootNode>
<Node1>a</Node1>
<Node2>b</Node2>
<subRootNode1>
    <subNode1>c</subNode1>
    <subNode2>d</subNode2>
</subRootNode1>
<subRootNode2>
    <subNode1>e</subNode1>
    <subNode2>f</subNode2>
</subRootNode2>
<Node3>g</Node3>
<Node4>h</Node4>
</rootNode>
```

I want this to splitted in two XMLs one with subRootNode1 and other with subRootNode2 i.e.

```
<rootNode>
<Node1>a</Node1>
<Node2>b</Node2>
<subRootNode1>
    <subNode1>c</subNode1>
    <subNode2>d</subNode2>
</subRootNode1>
<Node3>g</Node3>
<Node4>h</Node4>
</rootNode>
```

AND

```
<rootNode>
<Node1>a</Node1>
<Node2>b</Node2>
<subRootNode2>
    <subNode1>e</subNode1>
    <subNode2>f</subNode2>
</subRootNode2>
<Node3>g</Node3>
<Node4>h</Node4>
</rootNode>
```

I want to do this using XSL.

Comment: What version of XSLT (and if 1.0, which XSLT processor)?

Comment: Actually i am not sure about any of these. I think xslt 2 can work.

Comment: If you're not sure, find out. See here how: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23651724/number-format-for-csv-using-xslt1-0/23656696#23656696